# Jquery hide error in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, hide

I'm working on a page with mutiple divs that hide via the following jQuery code:

```
// Special Offers Page
    $(".details").click(function(){
            $(this).parents("div.special-offer").children(".hiddencontent").toggle();
        return false;
    });
```

Here's the page for who needs to see the entire code: http://www.daraayuvillas.com/special-offers/

It works just fine in Chrome/Safari but bugs in Firefox - I just can't find an explanation for which it wouldn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is the error? I tried this in chrome and firefox and it seems to work fine.

Comment: I'm getting 2 404 errors on your javascript files. BrowserSniffer and DYNCalendar (which are for some reason in an /images/ folder), which leads to a lot more javascript errors.

Comment: those have been added by a third party and are not my fault :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox does not like the positioning of your floats. It seems to work if you move the  `float:left` from the class `.special-offer` to it's parent div node with the class `.post`